# How are nmap arp pings implemented?

Tags: nmap

> Nmap issues the raw ARP requests and handles retransmission and
> timeout periods at its own discretion

The above is how nmap describes arp pings, but how is a layer 2 concept returned to the sender (me). Each frame is re-constructed at each hop, so unless through some tunneling, I don't understand how we get the arp response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARP scans are only available in the same network, not across network boundaries (i.e. where a packet needs to be routed).

The primary use for ARP scans is local network enumeration, as they are much faster, as nmap bypasses the OS' ARP cache.

Comment: Ah okay -- my misunderstanding was I thought arp pings were implemented across network boundaries. This makes so much more sense.

Comment: @HappyJerry It is indeed impossible for ARP to work across network boundaries, as you correctly stated in your question. But they're really really useful in the local network, so nmap will *always* attempt to use ARP pings when scanning hosts on the same network, even if other scan types are specified (unless ARP pings are explicitly disabled).  This behavior is documented in [Host Discovery](https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html) and [Host Discovery Techniques](https://nmap.org/book/host-discovery-techniques.html)